# How to list available storage drivers in docker?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ubuntu-16.04

Info shows:

```
Storage Driver: vfs
```

Kubernetes doesn't like it, `kubeadm init` prints:

```
unsupported graph driver: vfs
```

How to list available drivers?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a list of available drivers by the command line (with a "service docker status" you can only see the one being used), you can learn about it on the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/) and proceed to configurate one of your choice, they don't work "out of the box" but it's just a question of OS configuration.

P.D.: if  want a quick workaround use a previous version like docker 12.3.